# Stretching of button images smaller iphone

Tags: ios

I have a stack view that I have uibuttons that are embedded in inside (as well as a normal image view).

Everything looks good except when I get to the iPhone SE resolution. There, the buttons are distorted. What is the best way to avoid this issue at the super small screen sizes?

All button views are aspect fit

---

Normal way it should be rendered:

[image]

iPhone SE rendering:

[image]

Stack view attributes:

[image]

Stack view constraints (no constraints on items inside stack view):

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your button's image attributes?

Comment: @MarinaAguilar added details

Comment: stop using interface builder for anything and programtically create the view, access the UIButton's UIimageView and UILabel and set the content modes on both individually

Comment: What determines the top/height of the stack view?